# What is the meaning of the ocaml object syntax `object(...)`?

Tags: ocaml

What does the "object(self: something)" means in Ocaml, inheritance?

```
class tcp_messaging my_address my_cookie (drop_it: drop_function) =
....
object(self : # messaging )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sharp sign in front of a class name denotes a class type which contains at least the type of the class, so it is more or less an interface denotation.

Ocaml doesn't have a special keyword to reference an object in its implementation (like the keyword `this` in C++ for instance). Instead, it provides a flexible syntax to define the name which will be used to reference the object instance (in this case the name `self` is used). It appears that this naming is actually the one used generally (it's kind of a practice), so you will see it very often.

So basically, that syntax let you bind the object to a name, and add a constraint on that name, so that the implementation must implement at least that type. Without the `#`, the class implementation would need to be exactly of that type.

Answer (score 2):

Incidentally, `self` binds the value of object itself. Read the following [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00//manual017.html#class-body).

Answer (score 1):

`object(self)` defines a value to the current object.

The `: #messaging` bit says that it implements the interface `messaging`.